# How to update database on change of checkbox? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, checkbox

How can I update the database when the user clicks on the Checkbox?
So when the checkbox is checked and the user clicks on it, then the database will update a value and the checkbox remains unchecked until its checked again.

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type='checkbox' name='all' checked>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type='checkbox' name='all'>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I like to have this written in javascript.
I don't have any code because I don't have knowledge on how to build this.
Please help me with this.

Comment: Database is, under assumption of logic, used on the server, and I assume that this javascript code you want is, again under assumption, used on the client. So you need to have an ajax request to a server, which a server will handle and this turns into a non-javascript question from there on out.

Comment: I just have a connection to my Mysql database

Comment: To my knowledge, which is admit-ably limited, JavaScript does not connect to a database, you did that in PHP or ASP, on the backend, which is also what you will use to make the queries and changes to the database. Javascript only makes an AJAX request, what the server does is up to the backend.

Comment: You cannot update a MySQL database client-side. You need to do it server-side using NodeJS, PHP or any other server-side scripting language. Client-side Javascript here would be used to make an AJAX Request after a checkbox get checked or unchecked to trigger server-side script that will update your MySQL database.

Comment: I made an connection using PHP :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by doing an `AJAX` request to a `PHP` page.
The `PHP` page handles my `DB` changes.

```js
function update(elem) {
  if ($(elem).is(':checked')) {
    var checked = 1;
  } else {
    var checked = 0;
  }
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: {
      "active": checked,
    },
    cache: false,
    contentType: "application/json",
    crossDomain: true,
    processData: false,
    url: "/update.php
    success: function(data) {
      console.log("updated");
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
      console.log(xhr.status);
    }
  });

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type='checkbox' name='all' checked onclick="update(this)">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type='checkbox' name='all' onclick="update(this)">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```